# Is it grammatically correct to use [a] after [between] and a number?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, articles, sentence-structure

What is the grammatical issue with the following sentence, if any?

> Love is a game between a two.

Someone argued that it is improper the article should be deleted. hence, love is a game between two is the correct form.  Which one is correct? is it a matter of grammar or style?

Comment: Even when you remove the (totally ungrammatical) indefinite article, *Love is a game between two* is not an idiomatically natural English statement. Although you might think what "two" refers to is contextually obvious, it really needs to be explicitly stated *(Love is a game between two **people**).* Personally I don't much like the use of "between" in this context, so might prefer something like *Love is a game **involving** two people,* but opinions may vary on that point.

Comment: Note that it's quite valid to include the article in contexts like *I often see birds in my garden. In fact I can see **a dozen** right now.* But that doesn't work with simple cardinal numbers, so you *can't* say *??...I can see **a two** right now*. I don't know exactly why the article is required for values like ***a** dozen, **a** hundred, **a** thousand*, but not for values like *two, twenty, ninety-nine*.

Comment: Related: [articles before numbers.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85957/articles-before-numbers)

Comment: One does find everyday examples in specific contexts of articles being used before numbers, such as a client saying to an optician: *I can see a two, followed by a three*. Or a householder saying to a worker putting numbers on a gatepost: *Please move the three up slightly*. In both cases, the word *number* is elided.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you could *artfully* say *"Love is a game between a One and a Two"*.  Not that it would be particularly *clever*, but you could.  *"Love is a game between one and two"* is considerably better.  But this is a very poetic case and I'm just muddying the waters ...

Comment: @Andrew: Native speakers could "artfully" do many things with language that are either irrelevant of actively counterproductive for nns attempting to *learn* English. I focused on the difference between ***a** two* and, say, ***a** dozen* because even if I can't explain *why* those are different, at least most native speakers would agree when that article is needed, and when it's invalid. But explaining exactly why I don't much like *Love is a game for two* whereas I'm fine with [***Sex** is a game for two*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+a+game+for+two+not%22) is trickier.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think in your examples the "a" is standing in for "one". A dozen = one dozen, a thousand = one thousand. It doesn't work with other numbers because you can't say "one two" or "one five hundred".

Answer (score 1):

The previous  comments are correct.

You need to add **people** because the word **two** then has a noun to describe or modify.

In the sentence :

Love is a game between **two** **people**.

**two = adjective

people= noun**

Because the noun is plural  it is not preceded by an **indefinite article = a**

Comment: You can also use the word that means two people by saying, "Love is a game between a twosome."  It all sounds very flowery though.

Answer (score 0):

It can be correct if the author or speaker is trying to be *excessively poetic* or frivolous with the expression.

It is not an expression one would use in otherwise normal writing or speech.  A simple statement of fact would be:

> Love is a game between two people.

Answer (score 0):

[a] cannot be used with the word two, [a] is always used with singular pronouns. For eg "a book", "an elephant".